# Is it possible to mask values in where clause of a SQL statement using JSQLParser?

Tags: java, sql, jsqlparser

I have to mask or remove the values in where clause of my sql statement. I'm using JSQL parser for parsing.Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: what is the query that you tried?

Comment: What version of JSQLParser do you use?

Comment: Maybe this one helps: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-building, looking at replacing string values.

Comment: Thanks @wumpz I am done.